# How to find all the rows with same specific value for a column that is repeated specific time in the dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas database for which i want to find all the rows that have same value for column `A` and are repeated specific amount of time (I call it `size`):

```
   A    B
0  1  yes
1  2   no
2  3   no
3  2  yes
4  3   no
5  4  yes
```

So if i have `size = 2`, only column values 2 and 3 are repeated 2 times in column `A`, so the result should be like this:

```
   A   B1   B2
0  2   no  yes
1  3  yes   no
```

I have done this code, but it is kinda slow for large data since it uses `for` loop, so i am looking for suggestion to improve:

```
def load_data(self, size):
        '''Creates a data frame of all orders with number of items in that order equals to argument size'''
        data = pd.read_csv(self.file_name, sep="\t", header=0, 

        #grouping
        grouping = data.groupby('A')
        df =  grouping.filter(lambda x: len(x) == size) #filters all the data with specific size
        values = []
        for i in range(0, len(df)):
            if i% size == 0:
                dat = df[i: i+size]
                temp = dat[['B']]
                temp_values = np.append(df.iloc[i][0], temp.values.flatten())
                values.append(temp_values)

        new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(values))
        return new_df
```

Answer (score 2):

```
g = df.groupby('A')
c = g.cumcount() + 1
s = g.A.transform('size').to_numpy()

df.set_index(['A', c]).B[s == 2].unstack().add_prefix('B').reset_index()

   A  B1   B2
0  2  no  yes
1  3  no   no
```

---

If you have more columns

```
g = df.groupby('A')
c = g.cumcount() + 1
s = g.A.transform('size').to_numpy()


d = df.set_index(['A', c])[s == 2].unstack()
d.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in d.columns]
d.reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I had another column "C"?

Answer (score -1):

IIUC, you can make do with `groupby().transform`:

```
df[df.groupby('A').B.transform('size').eq(2)]
```

gives

```
    A   B
1   2   no
2   3   no
3   2   yes
4   3   no
```